# Can Mathematica reformulate an expression, by constructing it around another expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Can Mathematica reformulate an expression, by constructing it around another expression?

For example, I my case, I have the following expression:

```
4 c v^2 (-1 + Subscript[p, 1]) (-1 + Subscript[p,2]) (t^2 Subscript[p, 2] + Subscript[p, 1] (t^2 + (c - 2 t^2) Subscript[p, 2]))
```

and I wish to investigate if I can reformulate it around the expression

```
4 c (1 - Subscript[p, 1]) Subscript[p, 1] v^2
```

Is there functionality in Mathematica, which performs this kind of task?

Comment: It's not clear, to me, what you mean by "constructing something around expression" and by "reformulate something around expression". Is the first expression in your post an input and second - expected output? Or are both expressions inputs, what is expected output then?

Comment: Clarification: suppose I define 4 c (1 - Subscript[p, 1]) Subscript[p, 1] as X. Is there a function in Mathematica that allows me to express 4 c v^2 (-1 + Subscript[p, 1]) (-1 + Subscript[p,2]) (t^2 Subscript[p, 2] + Subscript[p, 1] (t^2 + (c - 2 t^2) Subscript[p, 2])) in another way, which incorporates X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the polynomial expressions in the question [`PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html) is applicable.

```
expr = 
 4 c v^2 (-1 + Subscript[p, 1]) (-1 + 
    Subscript[p, 2]) (t^2 Subscript[p, 2] + 
    Subscript[p, 1] (t^2 + (c - 2 t^2) Subscript[p, 2]))

bexpr = 4 c (1 - Subscript[p, 1]) Subscript[p, 1] v^2

PolynomialReduce[expr, bexpr, t]
```

[image]